# Creating a List View that starts with the Second Item/Row

Tags: list-view, custom-list, view

I am creating two views of a 'News' List.

1. The First View displays the most recently added item to the list.
2. The Second View needs to display the 2nd, 3rd and 4th most recently added items.

Is there a way from within the Edit View screen, to skip the first row of a queried list?

(I am trying to render these views from within ShortPoint elements, so a normal Content Query or Content Search related solution will not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P-Bagles,

Although I am not 100% sure if this is the best way to achieve this (you may look into JSLINK CONDITIONS), this method does meet the requirement that you are looking to achieve, with some small caveats in regards to sorting, etc.

**Here is how you can achieve this.**

**COUPLE IMPORTANT NOTES for the LISTED code:**

- *IMPORTANT:::: YOU WILL NEED TO CHANGE #scriptWPQ2 to the webpart ID
  that is on your page, you can do an inspect element to find the web
  part ID
- The **tr:eq(2)** part of the code will hide the FIRST row item ONLY in the list,
  if you want to hide additional ones you will replicate this line of code and add additional tr:eq(3), tr:eq(4) (EXAMPLE AT THE BOTTOM), you
  will need a new .html for each views PAGE with a content editor linked to
  each .html file ON EACH PAGE!*

---

**SOLUTION:**

1. Create your views, each view will get its own .aspx page
2. In your site assets library create a .html file and put this code

**THE CODE for html file(s):**

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

// IMPORTANT:::: YOU WILL NEED TO CHANGE #scriptWPQ2 to the webpart ID that is on your page, you can do an inspect element to find the web part ID
// This tr:eq(2) will hide the FIRST row item ONLY in the list, if you want to hide additional ones you will replicate this code, you will need a new .html for each view with a content editor linked to each .html file
        $('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(2)').hide();
        //$('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(3)').hide();
        //$('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(4)').hide();
        //$('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(5)').hide();
    })
    </script>
```

3. Save the html file with a .html extension
4. Add a content editor to each views aspx page and link it to each corresponding .html file (i.e. hide1row.html hide2rows.html)

---

Again, here is an example of **hide1row.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(2)').hide();
    })
    </script>
```

---

AND FOR **hide2rows.html** (notice there is 2 .hide() commands)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(2)').hide();
        $('#scriptWPQ2 tr:eq(3)').hide();
    })
    </script>
```

[image: INSPECT ELEMENT ON PAGE]

[image: SNIPPET OF CODE IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER]

Understanding this is a big workaround, once you get the hang of it, it should be pretty easy to achieve and replicate.

Good Luck!

Comment: If you are already loading in jQuery to your sharepoint site then you can omit the <script src="jquery CDN link"> in the code. Just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out!! And report back on what happens (:

Comment: Great, let us know :)

Comment: This worked really well. I had to change it up a bit to specifically target the elements I needed, but the concept of simply hiding the elements is really simple and straight forward, thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you! Woop! :)